# UICollectionView and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to create a `UICollectionView` whose width/height and coordinates are defined using AutoLayout (using SnapKit).  When using the default `UICollectionView` constructor it fails with the following reason:

> reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

The only constructor that allows a layout to be passed in, also requires a `frame`, so I tried using `CGRectZero` as the value for the `frame` like so:

```
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

I then used `SnapKit` to setup the constraints like so:

```
collectionView?.snp_makeConstraints { make -> Void in
        make.width.equalTo(view)
        make.height.equalTo(300)
        make.top.equalTo(someOtherView)
    }
```

However, when doing so the `UICollectionView` is never rendered.  In fact, I do not see the data source being called at all.

Any thoughts on how to use AutoLayout with a `UICollectionView` or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added the collection view to the view hierarchy with "addSubView"?

Comment: You have height and given its top position, you have width but where is its left or right position ? That will likely fix it :)

Comment: @Darko Yes, it's been added to the hierarchy.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne Thanks, but unfortunately that did not work.  Very strange.  I feel like because the frame is set to `CGRectZero` it assumes there is no sense in drawing the cells.

Comment: CGRectZero should not matter at all, since you are using autolayout, the sizing would be done with autolayout. How about your collectionViewLayout. Are you subclassing UICollectionViewLayout or UICollectionViewFlowLayout, are you managing collectionViewSize by yourself.

Comment: Can you by any chance try the new AutoLayout syntax provided with iOS 9 beta. It is similar to SnapKit `yourView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(otherView.widthAnchor).ative = true` and see if the problem is maybe with SnapKit!? And remember setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for your view.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne you don't have to create the left or right constraints as the default x position will be 0 and the width constraint will do the job here. ;)

Comment: Is that the behavior with SnapKit, or default behavior for any autolayout constraints ? I thought that without an incomplete x, y, width and height the layout would be ambigous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This following code works just fine for me and I got a red and empty collection view.

`Xcode 7 beta 4 - Swift 2.0 - AutoLayout syntax from iOS 9`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

    collectionView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.widthAnchor).active = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(300).active = true
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true
}
```

I never used `SnapKit` but I do know it. The syntax provided in my code is almost the same as in your example. So it is only a clue that something is wrong with `SnapKit` or how you use it.

I hope this can help you somehow.

Comment: Ugh..so I was setting the constraints too early and the collection view was actually null.   SnapKit did not alert me/raise exception to this.  When I tried your code, the exception was thrown, and I was able to fix the ordering.  Thank you!

Comment: I know, somebody downvoted eveything without even commenting why.